# Assigning to a std::shared_ptr member variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class `foo`, with a member `bar` of type `std::shared_ptr<int>`:

```
class foo
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> bar;
    /*other stuff here*/
};
```

In that class I want to assign a `new int` to `bar`. But I can't write `bar = new int();` as the pointer does not have a public assignment operator.

How *should* I do this? I could `std::move` or `std::swap` but neither of those seem right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `reset` for this:

```
bar.reset(new int());
```

This will `delete` the current contents (if any) and set the internal pointer to that returned by the `new` expression.

Answer (score 14):

`bar = std::make_shared<int>();` is one way, especially if you like to retain the tractability of an assignment operator.

Comment: Saw your edit. Does that change still initialise the `int` to 0? `new int()` would, `new int` wouldn't.

Comment: `std::make_shared<int>(new int())` isn't valid; `make_shared` perfect-forwards the arguments to the `T` constructor. It's specified to construct the object using `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` so if there are no args, it'll be value-initialized.

Comment: @Bathsheba: That's right, there are no "uninitialized" forms of any of the `make_*` functions. I think something like that was proposed once (as part of a proposal for allowing sized array types for make_{shared,unique}), and the proposal came with a make_*_uninitialized form that uses default-initialization. In general, the standard library makes it very hard to produce uninitialized values, even though sometimes that's what you need...

Comment: When would you *need* an uninitialized value? Never mind the tiny bit of performance, which is often irrelevant because the optimizer removes the extraneous assignment in the release build. The only other thing I can think of is for debugging with instrumentation, e.g. valgrind/memcheck or ubsan. Valgrind has an API that allows defining entire address ranges as "uninitialized", though, which has many uses beside the shared int example and also serves to make the intent explicit.

Comment: I don't. I wanted reassurance that @TartanLlama 's edit didn't introduce any possibility of an uninitialised variable. Their's, and Kerrek SB's expertise assures me that is not the case.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, my question is directed at @KerrekSB.

Comment: @ArneVogel: Suppose you're receiving data from the network and you want to store it, or your need an output buffer for something like `snprintf`. You need a dynamic array, but you never read the initial values. There's currently no standard library component that gives you such "write-only" storage.